# Duplicate zip entry in project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I have a little problem compiling a project I'm working on. The proguard wrror I'm getting is "(Duplicate zip entry [guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Ascii.class])".

The problem lies with the project itself... it uses 2 external libraries in the form of AARs. The first library has the guava-18.0.jar impeded in it.

The second library has a different version of the same classes from guava-18(probably an older version of them) copied in the classes.jar from the library. They basically copied the source files in their project.

Needles to say the project has to work with both libraries and we can't get another build from either of them. So how can I make them work along... I'm thinking they both will have to use their version of the guava classes since changes in API may have occurred.

I tried to use

```
{
        exclude(group: 'com.google.guava')
    }
```

in the build gradle for the libraries but with no success.

Any help is much appreciated.

L.E. - the build file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'dexguard'
apply from: '../gradle_scripts/sdktools.gradle'

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion project.getHighestAvailableTools("27.0.0")

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyzmo.sdkdemo"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        defaultConfig {
            versionCode 1
            versionName "0.0"
        }

        /*
        // DexGuard Settings
        debug {
            proguardFiles getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-debug-shrink.pro'), 'dexguard-project.txt'

            dependencies
            {


            }
        }

        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultDexGuardFile('dexguard-release.pro'), 'dexguard-project.txt'

            dependencies
            {


            }
        }
        /* */


        // Proguard Settings
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-project.txt'
            proguardFiles '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-android.txt', '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-project.txt'
            buildConfigField "String", "LOGGER_TYPE", "\"CONSOLE_DISK\""
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']

            dependencies
                    {


                    }
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            //proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-project.txt'
            proguardFiles '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-android.txt', '../proguard_dexguard_configs/proguard-project.txt'

            dependencies
                    {


                    }
        }
        /* */
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

ext.android_support_libs_version = "27.1.1"
ext.qr_libs_version = "3.3.0"
ext.lockpattern_version = "10.0.0"
ext.jdom_version = "2.0.6"
ext.jaxen_version = "1.1.6"
ext.spongy_version = "1.54.0.0"
ext.openiab_version = "0.9.8.7"
ext.metadataextractor_version = "2.9.1"
ext.jcifs_version = "1.3.18-kohsuke-1"
ext.commonslang_version = "3.5"
ext.aboutlibraries_libs_version = "5.9.3"

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs "../app/libs"
    }
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    api (name:'SIGNificant4AndroidSDK', ext:'aar')
    api "haibison.android:lockpattern:$lockpattern_version"
    api "com.android.support:support-annotations:$android_support_libs_version"
    api "com.android.support:support-compat:$android_support_libs_version"
    api "com.android.support:support-core-utils:$android_support_libs_version"
    api "com.android.support:support-core-ui:$android_support_libs_version"
    api "com.android.support:support-media-compat:$android_support_libs_version"
    api "com.android.support:support-fragment:$android_support_libs_version"
    api "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$android_support_libs_version"
    api "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$android_support_libs_version"
    api "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$android_support_libs_version"
    api "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$android_support_libs_version"
    api (name:'Sources_Custom_Support_Library_v4', ext:'aar')
    api (name:'SIGNificant4AndroidSDK_JniBitmapOperationsLibrary', ext:'aar')
    api (name:'SIGNificant4AndroidSDK_QRCodeScanner', ext:'aar')
    api ("com.google.zxing:core:$qr_libs_version")
    api ("com.google.zxing:android-core:$qr_libs_version")
    api ("com.google.zxing:android-integration:$qr_libs_version")
    api ("org.jdom:jdom2:$jdom_version") {transitive = true;}
    api ("jaxen:jaxen:$jaxen_version") {transitive = true;}
    api ("com.madgag.spongycastle:pkix:$spongy_version") {transitive = true;}
    api ("org.onepf:openiab:$openiab_version")
    api ("com.drewnoakes:metadata-extractor:$metadataextractor_version") {transitive = true;}
    api ("org.samba.jcifs:jcifs:$jcifs_version") {transitive = true;}
    api("com.mikepenz:aboutlibraries:$aboutlibraries_libs_version") { transitive = true; }
    api ("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:$commonslang_version")

    //Skype For Business
    compile(name: "SkypeForBusinessNative", ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: "SkypeForBusinessPlatform", ext: 'aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
    }
    compile(name: "SkypeForBusinessInjector", ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: "SkypeForBusiness", ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: "SkypeForBusinessNativeEnums", ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: "SkypeForBusinessTelemetryClient", ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: "SkypeForBusinessTelemetryService", ext: 'aar')
    compile(name: "android-database-sqlcipher", ext: 'aar')
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must change your codes above like this:

```
compile ('your lib'){
    exclude group:'com.google.guava'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `exclude group` with `module` specified:

```
implementation("group.id:artifact:version", {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
})
```

(or `compile` instead of `implementation`, if you're using older gradle plugin)

Comment: Same problem, "Duplicate zip entry [guava-18.0.jar:com/google/common/base/Ascii.class]"

Comment: @andreid can you post your setup of build.gradle? maybe there's some other error?

Comment: I've created a simplified project using just the requirements for the 2 libraries... and I've upgraded gradle to 3.x - still the same problem.. I've added the build file in the original question.